# Difference between html and * when setting color or fonts for the whole page

Tags: css, css-selectors

I watched a video and found the programmer used `* {}` to set the margin and padding, but used `html {}` to set the font color. I don't understand why he bothers to use `html {}` to set the font color? He could have used `* {}`
to set all those things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*` wildcard rule essentially says this style applies to all elements. It's usually discouraged from use because that has performance implications. I suspect the author has a pet hate of elements with default margin or padding and just salts the earth because of it.

I recommend using a real CSS reset or normalising snippet instead, for example https://dev.to/hankchizljaw/a-modern-css-reset-6p3

The difference in this context between `color` and `margin`/`padding` is that `color` is inherited from an element's parent by default, and `margin`/`padding` doesn't.

So if we set `* { color: green; }`, we'd have to write another rule like `p { color: inherit; }` to get that inheritance behaviour back.